# How to remove arrows on list item. I only need arrow on 2017

Tags: css

How to remove arrows on listitem. I only need arrow on 2017. For list items i need solid square. I have used nested unordered list but for only top UL i need arrow not for the second UL

```css
@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css");
ul#ulMeet li:before {
  content: "\e080";
  /*content: "\009B";*/
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-size: 10px;
  /*font-weight:bold;*/
  float: left;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: -14px;
  color: #999999;
}
```

```html
<ul id="ulMeet" style="list-style:none">
  <li>
    <h4><a id="lnk" href="#" style="text-align:left;" onclick="YearsToggle(event, 'div2017')">2017</a></h4>
    <div id="2017" style="display:none;">
      <center><strong>2017</strong></center><br />
      <ul>
        <li>Test1</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: Post your HTML code too ;)

Comment: Added HTML aswell

Comment: `ul#ulMeet > li:before` this only targets the children `li` of `ulMeet`

Comment: `ul#ulMeet ul li:before`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `ul#ulMeet li:before` with `ul#ulMeet > li:before` doing so, target the direct `li`children  of `ul#ulMeet`

```css
@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css");
ul#ulMeet> li:before {
  content: "\e080";
  /*content: "\009B";*/
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-size: 10px;
  /*font-weight:bold;*/
  float: left;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: -14px;
  color: #999999;
}
```

```html
<ul id="ulMeet" style="list-style:none">
  <li>
    <h4><a id="lnk" href="#" style="text-align:left;" onclick="YearsToggle(event, 'div2017')">2017</a></h4>
    <div id="2017">
      <center><strong>2017</strong></center><br />
      <ul>
        <li>Test1</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css");
ul#ulMeet > li:before {
  content: "\e080";
  /*content: "\009B";*/
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-size: 10px;
  /*font-weight:bold;*/
  float: left;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: -14px;
  color: #999999;
}

ul li ul, ul li ul li{
  list-style-type: square;
}
```

This will apply the arrow only if the li is an immediate child of #ulMeet and then for every ul nested inside of another ul, it will have square bullets.

Comment: All children are immediate

Comment: @Huangism "Elements matched by the second selector must be the immediate children of the elements matched by the first selector." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors

Comment: You should put that docs as part of the answer, I am just informing you that all children are immediate, the others are descendants